# Need awk command syntax inside Ansible

Tags: awk, ansible, runtime-error, syntax-error, escaping

The below command works fine:

```
awk '/java/ {print "PID is:" $2"\nProcess Dump is:\t" $0}' <(ps -ef | grep -v grep)
```

Output:

```
PID is:515
Process Dump is:    wladmin    515   506  0 Nov03 ?        01:11:39 /web/jdk-18.0.1.1/bin/java -jar remoting.jar -workDir /web/jenkinsprod -jar-cache /web/jenkinsprod/remoting/jarCache
PID is:22145
Process Dump is:    wladmin  22145 22140  0 Nov04 ?        00:54:18 /web/jdk-18.0.1.1/bin/java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/web/jenkins_windows/tmp -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -jar remoting.jar -workDir /web/jenkins_windows -jar-cache /web/jenkins_windows/remoting/jarCache
PID is:32703
Process Dump is:    wladmin  32703 32699  0 Nov03 ?        01:10:34 /web/jdk-18.0.1.1/bin/java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/web/jenkins/tmp -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -jar remoting.jar -workDir /web/jenkins -jar-cache /web/jenkins/remoting/jarCache
```

I wish to have the same command in ansible list. Tried the below:

```
---

- name: Concant and Print variable
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Test
      set_fact:
        process_dump: "{{ process_dump  | default([]) +  ['awk \'/' ~ item ~ '/ {print \"PID is:\" $2\"\nProcess Dump is:\t\" $0}\' <(ps -ef | grep -v grep)'] }}"
      loop:
        - 'java'
        - 'ssh'

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ process_dump }}"

    - command: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ process_dump }}"
```

However, I get the below error:

```
TASK [Test] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got 'string'. String: {{ process_dump  | default([]) +  ['awk '/' ~ item ~ '/ {print \"PID is:\" $2\"\nProcess Dump is:\t\" $0}' <(ps -ef | grep -v grep)'] }}"}
```

Can someone please explain and share the correct syntax?

Comment: What do you find confusing about the cited error, which is not even legal yaml, let alone ansible? Also, even if you snapped your fingers and it was legal yaml, [`command:` does not tolerate pipes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#synopsis) and for sure no `<(` syntax

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in the `set_fact` task. You have a problem with escaping.

Sometimes it is easier to escape a string or parts into separate variables to reduce complexity.

The `set_fact` task as loop works in the following notation:

```yaml
- name: set_fact version one with loop
  set_fact:
    process_dump: "{{ process_dump  | default([]) +  [cmd] }}"
  vars:
    cmd: 'awk ''/{{ item }}/ {print "PID is:" $2"\nProcess Dump is:\t" $0}'' <(ps -ef | grep -v grep)'
  loop:
    - 'java'
    - 'ssh'

- debug:
    var: process_dump
```

*For the variable `cmd` I specifically chose the quotation marks `'`, so you only have to escape the occurrences of the inner single quotes using `''` (two single quotes), otherwise no other characters. This is relatively simple. Then you can use `cmd` inside the Jinja expression.*

Alternatively you can implement the same functionality without a loop, that works like this:

```yaml
- name: set_fact version two without loop
  set_fact:
    process_dump_2: "{{ [cmd_p1] | product(apps) | product([cmd_p2]) | map('flatten') | map('join', '') }}"
  vars:
    cmd_p1: 'awk ''/'
    cmd_p2: '/ {print "PID is:" $2"\nProcess Dump is:\t" $0}'' <(ps -ef | grep -v grep)'
    apps:
      - java
      - ssh

- debug:
    var: process_dump_2
```

*Here your command is split into two parts (`cmd_p1` and `cmd_p2`). With [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) first part 1 (`cmd_p1`) is combined with the different applications (`apps`), afterwards part 2 (`cmd_p2`) is added. Now the commands for all applications can first be [flattened](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) and then [joined](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings).*

To execute the commands try the [`shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html).
The `command` module only allows simple commands, without pipelining or the like.

---

Results:

```
TASK [set_fact version one with loop] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=java)
ok: [localhost] => (item=ssh)

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "process_dump": [
        "awk '/java/ {print \"PID is:\" $2\"\\nProcess Dump is:\\t\" $0}' <(ps -ef | grep -v grep)",
        "awk '/ssh/ {print \"PID is:\" $2\"\\nProcess Dump is:\\t\" $0}' <(ps -ef | grep -v grep)"
    ]
}



TASK [set_fact version two without loop] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "process_dump_2": [
        "awk '/java/ {print \"PID is:\" $2\"\\nProcess Dump is:\\t\" $0}' <(ps -ef | grep -v grep)",
        "awk '/ssh/ {print \"PID is:\" $2\"\\nProcess Dump is:\\t\" $0}' <(ps -ef | grep -v grep)"
    ]
}
```